# Como colocar um ID numa variável? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, modelagem

Atualmente tenho uma view em que uma Tabela(Encomendas) está a ser carregada outra tabela(Cores)
Pretendo que dentro de cada encomenda seja lista a cor que tenha o mesmo ID que a encomenda.

Minhas Tabelas:

```
public partial class Programa
{
    public int ID_Programa { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Data_Registo { get; set; }
    public string Num_Encomenda { get; set; }
 }

public partial class Programa_Cor
{
    public int ID_Programa { get; set; }       
    public string Cor { get; set; }
}
```

Para usar os dois modelos numa unica view criei esta class

```
public class EncomendaViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Programa> Programas { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Programa_Cor> ProgramasCor { get; set; }
}
```

O que me pareceu más lógico foi associar um variável ao campo ID_Programa e comparar com ID_Programa da tabela Programas_Cor, mas é listado todas as cores por encomenda e não somente as que tem o mesmo ID.

Meu Controlador:

```
var cor = color.Where(x => id.Contains(x.ID_Programa)).ToList()

        var tables = new EncomendaViewModel
        {
            Programas = embOpen.ToList(),
            ProgramasCor = cor.ToList(),
        };
```

Agradeço a quem me possa ajudar!

**---------------------Update-----------------------------**

Minha View

```
<table class="table table-borderless table-sm " ;>
@foreach (var programa in Model.Programas)
{
    <tr style="border-top: 2px solid #cdd0d4;">

        <td style="width: 130px;">
            <b>Artigo: </b>@programa.Cod_Artigo

        </td>
        <td colspan="8">
            <b>Modelo: </b>@programa.Modelo
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 200px;">
            <b>Nº Encomenda: </b>@programa.Num_Encomenda
        </td>
        <td style="width: 170px;">
            <b>Ref.Cliente: </b>@programa.Ref_Cliente)
        </td>          
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="8">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                @foreach (var programa_Cor in Model.ProgramasCor)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 150px;">
                            @programa_Cor.Cor)
                        </td>                        
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

}
```

[image: view]

neste momento tenho as cores que estão carregadas são de apenas um id para teste, pois carrega mesma cor em todas as Encomendas

Comment: Sua modelagem tá um pouco estranha e a pergunta não foi específica o suficiente. Porém: acredito que você tenha um problema na sua modelagem. Pelo que eu entendi, o correto aí seria mudar a tabela de "ProgramaCor" para apenas "Cor" e na tabela "Programa" colocar uma chave estrangeira referenciando a tabela "Cor". Sendo assim, cada programa possuiria uma cor.

Comment: Da forma como está não faz sentido ter uma classe `Programa_Cor`, apenas uma propriedade `Cor` na classe programa

Comment: vou colocar a minha view em cima para compreenderem melhor o meu projeto

Answer (score 0):

**Seu problema está na modelagem do domínio.**

Alguns problemas:

1. Você está lidando com um relacionamento N x N (Muito pra Muitos), mas não criou uma *classe / tabela associativa* para especificar itens do relacionamento de Order x Color.
2. Você está usando nomenclaturas que não ajudam na abstração do problema e são diferentes do negócio do cliente (domínio do problema).

Vamos começar criando uma classe associativa:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Uma tabela associativa para guardar os itens do relacionamento N x N
/// </summary>
public class OrderColor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int QtdPecas { get; set; }
    public string Talao { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Observacoes { get; set; }
}
```

Aproveite para melhorar as nomenclaturas das entidades para facilitar a análise. Por exemplo, invés de usar o nome **Programa**, chame de **Order**, e **Color** invés de **Programa_Cor**.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Pedido
/// </summary>
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Data_Registo { get; set; }
    public string Num_Encomenda { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Todas as cores escolhidas
    /// </summary>
    public List<OrderColor> Colors { get; set; } = new List<OrderColor>();

    public void Add(Color color)
    {
        var corEscolhida = new OrderColor { OrderId = this.Id, Color = color };
        Colors.Add(corEscolhida);
    }
}

public class Color
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Nome;
    }
}
```

Sua ViewModel continua igual, só adicionei um comentário para explicar a diferenças dessa propriedade Cores e a propriedade Cores da classe Order:

```cs
public class EncomendaViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Order> Encomendas { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Lista todas as cores disponíveis
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<Color> Cores { get; set; }
}
```

Para vermos como fica o uso, criei uma implementação de exemplo em ConsoleApplication:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("TODAS AS CORES");

    // cria lista de cores
    var cores = new List<Color>();
    var branco = new Color { Id = 1, Nome = "BRANCO 500" };
    var lima = new Color { Id = 1, Nome = "LIMA 540" };
    var azul = new Color { Id = 1, Nome = "AZUL CLARO 560" };
    var taupe = new Color { Id = 1, Nome = "TAUPE 584" };

    cores.Add(branco);
    cores.Add(lima);
    cores.Add(azul);
    cores.Add(taupe);

    // lista na tela todas as cores disponíveis para serem escolhidas
    foreach (var c in cores)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("TODAS OS PEDIDOS");
    // cria as encomendas
    var encomendas = new List<Order>();
    var encomenda1 = new Order() { Id = 29798 };
    var encomenda2 = new Order() { Id = 29799 };

    encomenda1.Add(branco);
    encomenda1.Add(taupe);
    encomenda2.Add(lima);
    encomenda2.Add(azul);
    encomenda2.Add(taupe);

    encomendas.Add(encomenda1);
    encomendas.Add(encomenda2);

    // cria a viewmodel
    var model = new EncomendaViewModel
    {
        Encomendas = encomendas,
        Cores = cores
    };

    foreach (var o in model.Encomendas)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"PEDIDO - Artigo: {o.Id}");
        Console.WriteLine("CORES DO PEDIDO: ");

        foreach (var c in o.Colors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Cor: {c.Color} | Observacoes: {c.Observacoes}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
TODAS AS CORES
BRANCO 500
LIMA 540
AZUL CLARO 560
TAUPE 584
------------------------------------------------
TODAS OS PEDIDOS

PEDIDO - Artigo: 29798
CORES DO PEDIDO:
Cor: BRANCO 500 | Observacoes:
Cor: TAUPE 584 | Observacoes:

PEDIDO - Artigo: 29799
CORES DO PEDIDO:
Cor: LIMA 540 | Observacoes:
Cor: AZUL CLARO 560 | Observacoes:
Cor: TAUPE 584 | Observacoes:
```